# RecyclerView - How do I pass the position of onBindViewHolder to my ViewHolder class?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to setup onClickListeners inside my ViewHolder class, but I need the position of each. How can I pass the position from onBindViewHolder to my 
ViewHolder class?

```
@NonNull
@Override
public AdapterAllComments.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_rv_allcomments_container, viewGroup, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterAllComments.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCommentId.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{



    LinearLayout viewHolderLayout;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        viewHolderLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_child_layout);

    }
}
```

Comment: why you wanna do that. maybe there is a better way of what you trying accomplish. and yes it possible to do that with this.getAdapterPosition()

Comment: @lvl4fi4 it's because I want to set an onclickListener inside the viewHolder to get the index from an Array using the viewHolder's position

Comment: if all you want is onclick on the items then you can use interface . i will post it in answer

Comment: @lvl4fi4 Is it bad practice to setOnClickListeners inside onBindViewHolder? This is what I am currently doing

Comment: yes , it is not a correct way of doing it

Comment: I'm trying to setup the onClickListeners inside public class ViewHolder, but I need the position for each ViewHolder so I can get index in Array. So far this.getAdapterPosition() is returning -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this adapter from my other project :

```
    public class ChildrenRvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildrenRvAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    private Context context;

    public ChildrenRvAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.children_rv_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String name = mData.get(position);
        holder.tv_name.setText(name);
        setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView tv_name;
        Button btn_remove;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            btn_remove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_remove);
            btn_remove.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    }
}
```

so you create `interface` in your adapter and also declare it in local `mClickListener` and implement it in ViewHolder class and `setonclick` where you create the `viewholder`:

```
    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        btn_remove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_remove);
        btn_remove.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

just note that i set it on a `button` but you can set it on `itemView`
also on any `view` that have the `setOnClickListener` so you can use :

`itemView.setOnClickListener(this);`

then from your activity or fragment and wherever using the adapter, just implemet the `onlick` `interface` and after initializing the adapter use the method that we created `public void setClickListener` in our adapter, to local interface in the adapter

```
 public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}
```

activity:

```
public class ChildrenEditDialog extends Dialog implements IChildren.IView, ChildrenRvAdapter.ItemClickListener
```

and in activity `onCreate` or somewhere else:

```
 childrenRvAdapter = new ChildrenRvAdapter(c, dataSource);
    childrenRvAdapter.setClickListener(this);
```

and you have onlcick in your activity/fragment/dialog/etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewHolders `getAdapterPosition()` for getting current position of ViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current position of the onBindViewHolder to ViewHolder class `getAdapterPosition()` can be used.

As an example,

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    LinearLayout viewHolderLayout;

    viewHolderLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_child_layout);

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        viewHolderLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            lastClickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        });

    }
}
```