# How to pass edittext values from recyclerview adapter to activity in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

[image: I have added the page]I have two details page for selecting the court type. In first detailpage i have to select checkbox and pass the values to next detail page,in that I am getting the passed values in a recyclerviewv in which contains textview and an edittext. Now I have to enter the rate for each court in edittext and pass the value from adapter to activity which I have to set in activity button click. I am not able to pass the edittext values. So please help me on this.

DetailsActivity:

```
 public class Details1Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewItemInterface {

    RecyclerView rv, rt;
    private List<RegCompleteModel> details2Lists;
    private List<FacilityModel> lists;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    APIService service;
    private FacilityAdapter adapter;
    List<Details1PageModel> list;
    private Button mNextButton;
    List<String> ls;
    ArrayList<String> mRateList;
    List<String> mIds;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details1);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {

            ls = new ArrayList<>();
            mIds = new ArrayList<>();
            ls = extras.getStringArrayList("types");
            mIds = extras.getStringArrayList("Ids");

            mRateList = new ArrayList<>();

            rt = findViewById(R.id.list_rateTypes);
            Details1Adapter dadapter = new Details1Adapter(ls,Details1Activity.this);
            rt.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Details1Activity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true));
            rt.setAdapter(dadapter);
            Log.d("List", ls.toString());

        }

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Details1Activity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        service = Apicall.createService(APIService.class, this);

        Call<FacilityList> call = service.getFacilities();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<FacilityList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FacilityList> call, Response<FacilityList> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    lists = response.body().getFacilities();
                    rv = findViewById(R.id.list_facilities);
                    adapter = new FacilityAdapter(lists, Details1Activity.this);
                    FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(Details1Activity.this);
                    layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
                    rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FacilityList> call, Throwable t) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });

        mNextButton=findViewById(R.id.details1Next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

DetailsAdapter:

```
 public class Details1Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Details1Adapter.ViewHolder> {

     private Context cntx;
    private List<String> intent;
    private static ArrayList<String> rating;

    public Details1Adapter(List<String> intent Context cntx){
        this.intent=intent;
        this.cntx=cntx;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_typeitems,viewGroup,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder,final int i) {

//        String typename = intent.get(i);
//            Log.d("Value", typename);
      //  Details2List mDetail=intent.get(i);

        viewHolder.rateType.setText(intent.get(i));

        viewHolder.editRate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                String rate=viewHolder.editRate.getText().toString();
                rating.add(rate);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return intent.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView rateType,editRate;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            rateType=itemView.findViewById(R.id.rateText1);
            editRate=itemView.findViewById(R.id.rateText_edit);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Access `mRateList` on button click.

Comment: you can pass it through `interface` check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56714141/2979171

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK  I tried the same but when i am typing for ex. 400 the value is getting as [4,40,400]

Answer (score 0):

solve this problem using interface.

create interface

```
interface MyListnear
{
   void addValue(String s);
}

adapter = new FacilityAdapter(lists, Details1Activity.this,new MyListnear(){

     public void addValue(String s){
     // Add value inside array
     }
});
```

and define interface in `adapter`

```
MyListnear lisner;

public Details1Adapter(List<String> intent Context cntx,MyListnear lisner)
   {

        this.intent=intent;
        this.cntx=cntx;
        this.lisner = lisner;
    }
```

implement `interface` click on button

```
like btn.setOnclickListnear(new .....) 
{
   lisner.addValue(viewHolder.editRate.getText().tostring())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..:) Could you please elaborate how can i add values as my button is used in activity(mNextButton).

Comment: I have edited my question with the image of screen for Details1Activity. On clicking the next button, I have to pass the two edittext values with textview ids and the facility selecting ids.

Comment: means you need to pass value of selected facility array to next activity am i right ?

Comment: s. in the image 5's & 7's are passed via intent that's the type's. I have to pass type id and it's rate I mean edittext and also the facility array id

Answer (score 0):

```
first


=====

> public class Facility implements Parcelable {
>     Integer id;
>     String name;
> 
>     protected Facility(Parcel in) {
>         if (in.readByte() == 0) {
>             id = null;
>         } else {
>             id = in.readInt();
>         }
>         name = in.readString();
>     }
> 
>     public static final Creator<Facility> CREATOR = new Creator<Facility>() {
>         @Override
>         public Facility createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
>             return new Facility(in);
>         }
> 
>         @Override
>         public Facility[] newArray(int size) {
>             return new Facility[size];
>         }
>     };
> 
>     public Integer getId() {
>         return id;
>     }
> 
>     public void setId(Integer id) {
>         this.id = id;
>     }
> 
>     public String getName() {
>         return name;
>     }
> 
>     public void setName(String name) {
>         this.name = name;
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public int describeContents() {
>         return 0;
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
>         if (id == null) {
>             dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
>         } else {
>             dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
>             dest.writeInt(id);
>         }
>         dest.writeString(name);
>     } }

=======================================


> public class SportzData implements Parcelable {
>     private String sevens;
>     private String fives;
>     private List<Facility> selectedFacilityList;
> 
>     public SportzData(String sevens, String fives, List<Facility> selectedFacilityList) {
>         this.sevens = sevens;
>         this.fives = fives;
>         this.selectedFacilityList = selectedFacilityList;
>     }
> 
>     protected SportzData(Parcel in) {
>         sevens = in.readString();
>         fives = in.readString();
>         selectedFacilityList = in.createTypedArrayList(Facility.CREATOR);
>     }
> 
>     public static final Creator<SportzData> CREATOR = new Creator<SportzData>() {
>         @Override
>         public SportzData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
>             return new SportzData(in);
>         }
> 
>         @Override
>         public SportzData[] newArray(int size) {
>             return new SportzData[size];
>         }
>     };
> 
>     public String getSevens() {
>         return sevens;
>     }
> 
>     public void setSevens(String sevens) {
>         this.sevens = sevens;
>     }
> 
>     public String getFives() {
>         return fives;
>     }
> 
>     public void setFives(String fives) {
>         this.fives = fives;
>     }
> 
>     public List<Facility> getFacilityList() {
>         return selectedFacilityList;
>     }
> 
>     public void setFacilityList(List<Facility> facilityList) {
>         this.selectedFacilityList = facilityList;
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public int describeContents() {
>         return 0;
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
>         dest.writeString(sevens);
>         dest.writeString(fives);
>         dest.writeTypedList(selectedFacilityList);
>     } }

================================================
and finally pass data from click on button


 Intent intent=new Intent(contacx,YourActivity.claas);

        intent.putExtra("Data",new SportzData(
                sevans.getText().toString(),
                five.getText().toString(),
                selectedArrayList));

===============================================

get data using intent

 Intent intent=getIntent();

        SportzData sportzData = intent.getParcelableExtra("Data");

        Log.d("<><>",sportzData.getFives());

        Log.d("<><>",sportzData.getSevens());

        List<Facility> facilityList = sportzData.getFacilityList();
```

Comment: Actually I am confused. Really Thank u for spending this much time to do the code. But I really have no problem for sending the values I will create a POJO class(retrofit based) while clicking next button. In this Details1Activity you can see I have passed the type values(arraylist) through intent. In before page I have to select checkboxes and pass those values to this page(Details1Activity). I just want to know how can i get edittext values with type ids so that I can set for passing values.

Comment: I think you have given the correct one first time itself, it will be helpful when u did that in my code itself.